# Updating JTabbedPanes with Data(Change's ) from Different Tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jcomponent

I have 4 JPanels in my TabbedPane. upon clicking a panel, i want to update the view on that JPanel  using data changes that might have happened in other Panels.
My Approach

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Component selectedTab =tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
            if(selectedTab instanceof VSwitchEditor){
                VSwitchEditor a= (VSwitchEditor)selectedTab;
                a.update(); 
            }
        }
    });
```

While this works , i was wondering if there is something  like the following that i can do rather than writing if blocks for all Tabs

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JPanel selectedTab =(JPanel)tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();

                selectedTab.**someFunction()**; 

        }
    });
```

I have tried overriding revalidate() and UpdateUI() but while initializing (Opening the application )i get a NullPointerException on the JComponents in the panels
So i was wondering if there is a Function In JPanel/JComponent or (some other Super Class ) that i can override to update my components

P.S - This is my first question and i have tried to make is as clear and precise as possible

Comment: Create an interface of some kind which provides the functionality that you need. Implement the interface on each view (or as an abstract class).  Use `if (selectedTab instanceof YourAwesomeInterface) {...}` to check that the component can be cast to you interface so you can call it's functionality...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thats what i did  - i was hoping that their exists some method , Thanks works